# Sample n elements from a list in R

Tags: r, list, sample

Suppose I have a list in R like this:

```
myList 
[[1]] 
[1] 4 6 7 9
 
[[2]] 
[1]  1  2  3  6  9 10
 
[[3]] 
[1]  12  41  2  8  22 6 16
```

I want to have n (for example 5) samples from the whole list like this:

```
sampledList
[[1]] 
[1] 4 9
 
[[2]] 
[1]  1 10
 
[[3]] 
[1]  22
```

Is there any straightforward solution for that?

Comment: You could use the base R sample function along with lapply

Comment: Do you have any other conditions.  I meant how you are deciding how many elements to be sampled from each list element

Comment: No, just the number of samples has to be N.

Comment: I see that you had 2 elements from first element, 2 from second and last one just 1

Comment: Ok, this is random. The next sample could be 5 from element 3 and nothing from elements 1 and 2. It is still acceptable. 
The things that I need are:
1- number of samples has to be N,
2- I have to know which sample is coming from which element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we need to do this at once on all elements, an option is to convert the `list` to a two column data.frame with `stack` - name the `list` elements with the sequence of list, and `stack`.  Then use `slice_sample` by specifying the `n`, `split` the sampled subset by the sequence column 'ind' and `unname` if necessary.

```
library(dplyr)
n1 <- 5
stack(setNames(myList, seq_along(myList))) %>% 
    slice_sample(n = n1) %>%
    {split(.$values, .$ind)} %>%
    unname
```

#### data

```
myList <- list(c(4, 6, 7, 9), c(1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 10), c(12, 41, 2, 8, 22, 
6, 16))
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a base R way.

```
set.seed(2021)

sampledList <- lapply(seq_along(myList), function(i) {
  setNames(myList[[i]], paste(i, seq_along(myList[[i]]), sep = "."))
})
sampledList <- sample(unlist(sampledList), 5)
split(unname(sampledList), sub("\\..*", "", names(sampledList)))
#$`2`
#[1]  3  2 10
#
#$`3`
#[1]  8 16
```

---

The code above as a function:

```
fun <- function(x, n = 5){
  y <- lapply(seq_along(x), function(i) {
    setNames(x[[i]], paste(i, seq_along(x[[i]]), sep = "."))
  })
  y <- sample(unlist(y), 5)
  split(unname(y), sub("\\..*", "", names(y)))
}

fun(myList)
```